# Use RxJava to emit a Single<List<Item>> from firestore given multiple ids

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm building an app that uses GeoFirestore to make location based queries of items stored in a firestore database. I have my function that gets a list of all the ids that meet the location criteria:

```
private fun loadIds(location: Location, distance: Double): Single<List<String>> {

    val query = geoFirestore.queryAtLocation(GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude), distance)

    val ids = ArrayList<String>()

    return Single.create<List<String>> {
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(object : GeoQueryEventListener {
            override fun onKeyEntered(uid: String, p1: GeoPoint?) {
                ids.add(uid)
            }

            override fun onGeoQueryReady() {
                it.onSuccess(ids)
            }

            override fun onKeyMoved(p0: String?, p1: GeoPoint?) {
            }
            override fun onKeyExited(p0: String?) {
            }
            override fun onGeoQueryError(p0: Exception?) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but now I'm having problems trying to combine the results of items from each id into a `Single<List<Item>>` as a return value.

This is what I was doing before:

```
fun loadItems(ids: List<String>): Observable<Item> {

    return Observable.create<Item> { emitter ->
        for (id in ids) {
            val reference = firestore.collection("items").document(id)
            reference.get().addOnSuccessListener {
                emitter.onNext(it.toObject(Item::class.java)!!)
                if (ids.indexOf(id) == ids.size - 1) {
                    emitter.onComplete()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where ids was the result of `loadIds()`. This worked fine, but in my activity where I called this I had to append each item in the activity as it came through and then listen for `onComplete`, which would sometimes fire before all items were even loaded.

I'm trying to improve my code and further separate the database logic from my activity, so I want to be able to return a `Single<List<Item>>` so once I get that in my activity I can just take it and run. I've been trying to figure it out on my own, but I'm pretty new to RxJava and don't quite understand it too well. Here is my latest attempt:

```
fun loadItems(filter: Filter): Single<List<Item>> {

    return Single.create<List<Item>> { emitter ->

        val items= mutableListOf<Item>()

        loadIds(filter.currentLocation, filter.distance).map {
            for (uid in it) {
                getItem(uid).map {item ->
                    items.add(item)
                }.subscribe()
            }
        }.subscribe { _ ->
            emitter.onSuccess(items)
        }

    }

}

private fun getItem(uid: String): Single<Item> {
    return Single.create<Item> { emitter ->
        firestore.collection("items").document(uid).get().addOnSuccessListener {

            it.toObject(Item::class.java)?.let { item ->
                emitter.onSuccess(item)
            } ?: run {
                emitter.onError(Throwable("Error finding item"))
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener {
            emitter.onError(it)
        }
    }
}
```

but obviously `onSuccess` is called almost immediately so I'm not getting any results.

Answer (score 2):

The `getItem` function looks fine, the problem lies in with the `loadItems` function.

You wrapped the Firebase callback mechanism nicely with `Single` in `getItem` function, but it is not necessary in the `loadItems` function. It's best to keep one chain in the function for readability reasons (IMO). That means, whenever you can, don't wrap the existing reactive object (`Observable`, `Single`, `Flowable`) into it's `subscribe`, but use `flatMap` (or any of it's versions).

```
fun loadItems(ids: List<String>): Single<List<Item>> {
    return Observable.just(ids)         // -> Observable<List<String>>
        .flatMapIterable { it }         // -> Observable<String>
        .flatMapSingle { getItem(it) }  // -> Observable<Item>
        // Create a single from the observable
        .collect<MutableList<Item>>(
            Callable { ArrayList<Item>() },
            BiConsumer { list, elem -> list.add(elem) }
        )   // -> Single<MutableList<Item>>
        .map { it } // -> Single<List<Item>>
}
```

Hope it helps.